# Fetch Value in reverse order using while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, fetch

I have a code which retrieves the values from data base.but i want to fetch this values in reverse order.See this example

```
While($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){


 echo $row['id']."<br>";//gives 1 and 2 and so on 
   echo $row['val']."<br>";// gives abc and def and so on

}
```

But i want

```
  2
    def
    1
   abc
```

How could i do this .i don't wanna use the Query for this like use of ORDER BY.so can i control this at PHP End??

Comment: If the order is important to you then you might want to consider using `order by` since mysql doesn't guarantee that the rows will be returned in the same order each time your query runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    $data[] = $row;
}

$data = array_reverse($data,true);

while($data){
}
```

Haven't tested it though

I tested it in [this site](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) and it works. Here's the snippet I used:

```
$data = array(1 => array("foo" => "bar"), 2 => true);
$data = array_reverse($data,true);
print_r($data);
```

Edit:
Using your edited answer, I got this:
    $data = array(1 => array(1, "abc"), 2 => array(2, "def"));

```
$data = array_reverse($data,true);
foreach($data as $d){
    echo "id>".$d[0]." | val>".$d[1]."<br />";
}
```

Comment: This would just return the elements in the particular row in reverse - instead of getting an array like `$array(id=>4, Name=>Fluffeh)` you would get `$array(Name=>Fluffeh, id=>4)`.

Comment: You're correct, I didn't thought of that, just threw it to the answer... My main point was the `array_reverse` method

Comment: Which was correct, but you should edit your answer to show that the OP should store the results of the query inside an array first, then reverse it after they have finished getting the data from the DB.

Comment: i used your answer bt my browser goes to infinite condition,can you plz again chk my updated question and give me a exact answer.

Comment: The full result? Please post the code and output and what it should be outputing

Answer (score 4):

Store your data in an array (in your while-loop). After that, you can use [array_reverse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to reverse item order.

Comment: Thanks for answer,but how can i use array_reverse ,i try to use like silentw old answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a cursor that iterates through your result set -moving backwards and forwards - using something like [PDO](http://au.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) - and probably similar variations for each other type of connection:

cursor_orientation

For a PDOStatement object representing a scrollable cursor, this value determines which row will be returned to the caller. This value must be one of the PDO::FETCH_ORI_* constants, defaulting to PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT. To request a scrollable cursor for your PDOStatement object, you must set the PDO::ATTR_CURSOR attribute to PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL when you prepare the SQL statement with PDO::prepare().

But using an array_reverse might be simpler. Having said that, ordering the data in the query would be simpler again (and probably much more efficient).

Comment: Thanks for answer Fluffeh,but i am not much aware from PDO.

Comment: @HarshalMahajan It is the newer, shinier and *safer* version of the `mysql_*` functions - which are being deprecated at the moment :)

Comment: ok i will definitely learn this.coz i seen here lots of senior members suggest to use PDO.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

for($i = $result->num_rows - 1; $i>0; $i--){
    $result->field_seek($i);
    $finfo = $result->fetch_field();
    echo $finfo->id;
    echo $finfo->val;
}
```

Comment: thnks for answer but i am not using mysqli..:(